# How to load more results in a web-scraping using python without using sellenium?

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests-html

I am scraping a website which show results with infinite scroll using javascript.

I am able to get only 10 results which are shown in first page. When you actually browse that site ,then when reaching at bottom of 10th result automatically more results gets loaded.

I am using only requests_html library of python and tried to render javascript using `r.render()` and it gives `RunTime error` in Spyder Ide then I tried to run in cmd in console and I got this error:

> "pyppeteer.errors.PageError: Protocol Error: Connection Closed. Most likely the page has been closed."

I tried looking for ajax data to get link and found but it complex to generate and gives data in json complexly and I want to scrape results fastly.

Kindly help me and please don't suggest Selenium. I want some tutorials also to work on another website which login directs to a more complicated complete Javascipt webpage then how to handle it using requests_html or with it some javascript running library if available.

Actually I want to grab results as I wanted 20,50 or 100 but I am getting only 10 because of jvascript infinite scrolling

Comment: Please include snippets of the relevant parts of your code.

Comment: I can't paste original snippet due to some reasons but its like showing everything one needs to.It use one single library requests_html but the result page load data dynamically by scrolling down and I am unable to get those results.